# QFile.write() writes only the first 22MBytes of large files

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qtnetwork, qtimer

I have following code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkReply *re = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://somesite/ai.bin")));
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
int timeInSeconds = 10;
QTimer *idleTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(idleTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),&loop,SLOT(quit()));
idleTimer->setInterval(timeInSeconds *1000);
idleTimer->start();
loop.exec();

//save
QFile file("C:/a.jpg");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
file.write(re->readAll());

ui->dbgOut->insertHtml("<font color='green'>OK</font><br>");
```

If the remote file is 5 MB, it works, bt if the file is abot 50 or 500MB, the program saves only the first 22 MBytes, while the process still downloads the file in background.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 seconds may not be enough to download it all, depending on your internet connection. Do not use the timer like this. To see the immediate effect, drop these lines:

```
int timeInSeconds = 10;
QTimer *idleTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(idleTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),&loop,SLOT(quit()));
idleTimer->setInterval(timeInSeconds *1000);
idleTimer->start();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!  Just a question. Do you know how i can download this file chunk-by-chunk? regards